# Typeerror in python with sum, list and range

Tags: python, while-loop

Good morning, srs,

Why this result in error?

```
n = float(input("Origin value : "))
K = float(1)
while K <= n:
   P = sum(list(range((float(K)), float(n*K))))
   K*= 1.05
print(P, "and", K)
```

In this case appear:

```
    P = sum(list(range((float(K)), float(n*K))))
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Thank you, srs!

Comment: `range` requires integer, not float.

Comment: "range" expects integer parameters but gets floats.

Comment: By the way, if you want a float value you don't need to write `K = float(1)`. A simple `K = 1.0` is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `range` function wants an integer (you can't do something 1.1 times, right?).  When you generate your range, decide whether you want to round the bounds up or down.